# Geometric proof that if n is a non-perfect square, then √n is irrational.

Tags: proof-writing, irrational-numbers, geometric-construction, square-numbers

I know there is a geometric proof of the irrationality of √2. I thought maybe this one could be generalized for ***√n*** when ***n*** is a non-perfect square, but I could not find something like that anywhere.

Does anyone know if such a geometric proof exist?
I'm researching on different kinds of proof for this theorem, but could only find the algebraic ones.

Comment: There is a nice one for $\sqrt{5}$ and relatives (golden section). Have not seen a general argument. One can imitate $\sqrt{2}$ geometric proof for $\sqrt{n}$ has  continued fraction expansion with short cycle length.

Comment: The usual idea for $\sqrt{2}$ is based on the Pythagorean theorem and $2=1^2+1^2$.  However on average [very few](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares)  integers can be expressed as the sum of two squares (all primes congruent to 3 mod 4 must appear an even number of times).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see a general solution.

However, this can be done for $\sqrt{n^2 + 1}$ and $\sqrt{n^2 - 1}$ given any integer $n > 1$.

You can find this result in TM Apostol's "Irrationality of The Square Root of Two -- A Geometric Proof" found [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CFAQFjAE&url=http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~marin/une_autre_crypto/articles_et_extraits_livres/irationalite/Apostol_T._irationality...-.pdf&ei=hfbIUbWsOpPK0gGa04HAAQ&usg=AFQjCNHD-wsYUBQgpIznclcXvf-UJ9Kd1A&sig2=AdTjbTMsChrGGeIZa67EUw&bvm=bv.48293060,d.dmQ&cad=rja).